# Google Analytics for iOS track to multiple account for same event

Tags: ios, google-analytics-api

I have two different web property id from two different accounts, say UA-1111-11, UA-2222-22
Now, in my iOS app, I need to log to both of them in the events. 
Is this even possible? If not, is there any workaround?

Here is my high level scenario:
I have an existing app where I use google analytics UA-1111-11 to track. Now, I had an agreement with company X (they have UA-2222-22). They told me that I need to send analytics tracking events to their account (UA-2222-22) from my app (and I want to keep UA-1111-11 for my own use).

Comment: Did you have any luck ? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a second instance of GANTracker? You could then build a wrapper that invokes the methods on both instances of the tracker.

Comment: @BrianV: Unfortunately GANTracker is singleton and source code is *not* available to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Google is working on their [v2 SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/advanced#multiple-trackers) and Android, and they added a feature for multiple trackers in the same application.
Currently, you can download [Google Analytics v2 beta 3 for iOS, and start playing with it](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources).

Answer (score 0):

Check [Google Analytics SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/advanced#multiple-trackers)

Sample code:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "GAI.h"

@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController
{
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Send a screen view to the first property.
  id tracker1 = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];
  [tracker1 sendView:@"/HomeScreen"];

  // Send another screen view to the second property.
  id tracker2 = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Z"];
  [tracker2 sendView:@"Home"];
}

@end
```

> Keep in mind that automated measurement features, like automatic
>   screen and uncaught exception measurement, will only use one tracker
>   to send data to Google Analytics. If you are using these features and
>   want to send data using other trackers, you will need to do so
>   manually.